# Arcgis map not loading in lightning component

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

Following is the very simple example I am trying to integrate in salesforce1 but its not showing. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

End result to produce - http://jsfiddle.net/6hfq0ggg/

Following is the code in my lightning component -

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/arcgis/esri.css" />
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/arcgis/init.js" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.myAction}" />
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Code in controller -

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        setTimeout(function(){      
            var map;
            require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
                map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                    center: [-56.049, 38.485],
                    zoom: 3,
                    basemap: "streets"
                });
            });
        }, 2000);
    }
})
```

I also uploaded `arcgis.zip` file in static resources containing two files, i.e esri.css, init.js.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things - all easy:

- use a single ltng:require for scripts and CSS is cleaner
- remove the setTimeout entirely. That will only cause you heartache (access checks will fail, timing issues, generally documented as an unneeded and unwise thing to do)

Now the harder part (not that hard):

- you are only including the bootstrapping resources in your ltng:require and static resource and that call to require() is attempting to pull in other resources (e.g. jsapi_en-us.js, svg.js, etc) that live on an external CDN which is not currently allowed as per our documented content security policy enforced sandbox.

The web resources that are being blocked will show up in the Networks tab in Chrome dev tools and errors should also be visible in the js console in your browser. ArcGIS is going to be a challenge to integrate into Lighning Components currently because of that CSP lockdown. We are working on a security feature (my current project in fact) to make this go away in Spring '16 (safe harbor of course) but I know that does not help you now. When I have been stymied by this kind of thing I have resorted to using an iframe with a Visuapforce page inside it in my Lightning Component which while it seems gross actually works quite well. Because VF pages are served from a namespaced domain they are allowed to directly reference external resources. If you need to communicate with the code inside the VF page from the LC or vice Verna it is not hard to use window.postMessage() to open a secure communication channel.